# Kак обратиться по имени свойства obj[word], если оно совпадает с Reserved Words javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, никак не найду.
Есть массив слов из строки, в котором я эти слова считаю.

```
  arrayOfWords.forEach(function(word: string){
      if (!obj[word]) {
        obj[word] = 1;
      } else {
        obj[word]++;
      }
    });
    return obj;
  }
```

Но в некоторых случаях слова в строке совпадают с Зарезервированными словами.
Например word == 'toString' или word == 'constructor'. И тогда никакой счетчик не работает.

Может быть проверять переменную word

```
  let reservedWord = false;
  try {
    eval('let ' + word + ' = 1');
  } catch {
    reservedWord = true;
  }
```

но что потом с ней делать? как заставить рассматриваться как обычную string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `!obj[word]` нужно использовать `obj.hasOwnProperty(word)`.

> [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)
>
> Возвращает логическое значение,
>   указывающее, содержит ли указанное свойство непосредственно объект,
>   или он унаследовал его по цепочке прототипов.

```js
const key = 'toString';
const obj = {};
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(key));
obj[key] = 1;
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(key));
```

Но лучше создать словарь `const obj = new Map<string, number>();` и пользоваться стандартными методами объекта [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) - `has` и `set`.

```
const string = 'dsds dds sdsdsdf toString constructor dds';

const obj = string.split(/\s+/).reduce(
    (acc, x) => acc.set(x, (acc.get(x) || 0) + 1),
    new Map<string, number>()
);

console.log(Array.from(obj));
```

Comment: @LilijaSternberg попробуйте словарь, в нём нет ничего страшного, это - тот же `obj`, с которым вы работаете сейчас, но немного более специализированный и строгий, что, скорее, добавляет удобства, чем не